# Delete an image completely in django gets SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: python, django

I have a model with an ImageField and when the user changes the image I want the old image to be deleted from the media/ folder:

```
fss = FileSystemStorage()
fss.delete(old_image.url)
```

I get SuspiciousFileOperation at / The joined path is located outside of the base path component

How can I remove the image completely?
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/useZ/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project/app/views.py", line 255, in settings
    fss.delete(old_image.url)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 305, in delete
    name = self.path(name)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 331, in path
    return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 29, in safe_join
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation(
```

Comment: Please post the full error output.

Comment: The joined path /media/images/image.png is located outside of the base path component /Users/user/Desktop/app/media

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.